# How to read file Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I load file using this:

```
public function fileUpload(Request $req)
{
    $req->validate([
        'file' => 'required|mimes:csv,txt,xlx,xls,pdf|max:2048'
    ]);
    $fileModel = new File();
    if ($req->file()) {
        $fileName = time() . '_' . $req->file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filePath = $req->file('file')->storeAs('uploads', $fileName, 'public');
        $fileModel->name = time() . '_' . $req->file->getClientOriginalName();
        $fileModel->file_path = '/storage/' . $filePath;
        $fileModel->save();

        $this->read($fileModel->file_path);

        return back()
            ->with('success', 'File has been uploaded.')
            ->with('file', $fileName);
    }
}
```

Then I tried to read file after upload file:

```
public function read($path)
{
   $file = FileStorage::get($path);
   dd($file);
}
```

But I get this error:

```
File does not exist at path /storage/uploads/1654468183_test.csv.
```

How to specify path properly?

Comment: what is `FileStorage` an alias for? `File` or `Storage`?

Comment: you can check path in `config/filesystems.php`

Comment: Yes, alias for `FileStorage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this way:

```
if ($req->file()) {
        $fileName = time() . '_' . $req->file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filePath = $req->file('file')->storeAs('uploads', $fileName, 'public');
        $fileModel->name = $fileName; //<--set the right filename
        $fileModel->file_path = '/storage/app/public/' . $filePath;
        $fileModel->save();

        $this->read($fileModel->file_path);

        return back()
            ->with('success', 'File has been uploaded.')
            ->with('file', $fileName);
    }
```

Comment: It does not work

Comment: File does not exist at path /storage/uploads/1654725649__SOURCE_(1)_valid.csv.

Comment: @Anastasia Usually if you chouse to use `public`, storage location is like that: `starage/app/public/` after that `storeAs()` returns `string` of the path - `uploads/filename.extension`

Comment: @Anastasia Here is the official docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Answer (score -1):

change this line

`$filePath = $req->file('file')->storeAs('uploads', $fileName, 'public');`

to this

`$filePath = $req->file('file')->storeAs('uploads/', $fileName, 'public');`

Comment: I still get the same error: 'File does not exist at path '